# Does geeksforgeeks website has an error regarding maximum number of nodes in a tree?

Tags: trees, decision-trees

I know that for a tree with a given height H, the maximum number of nodes on all levels is $n \le 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2+...+2^H = 2^{H+1}-1$. Basically it's for Perfect Binary Tree.

How come that [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lower-bound-on-comparison-based-sorting-algorithms/) well known website says that it's $2^H$? (they use `2^x` in the website).

Comment: It's a geometric sum so your formula is correct. Maybe they start counting at 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Unless that site changed, it says "A tree with maximum height x has at most 2^x leaves.". Leaves are nodes with no children, so is maximal with a full tree where it is the number of nodes on the final level.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis, you're right. My mistake. Regardless, `2^x` leaves can be only in Perfect Binary Tree, right?

Comment: Yes. A binary tree of height $x$ only has $2^x$ leaves if it is perfect (I said full in my previous comment, but should have said perfect). If any branch is cut short, it will reduce the number of leaves.